# FullCalendar.js external events data from classic asp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, fullcalendar

I am struggling to get external events data from asp into fullcalendar.js
I'm using the demo files from fullcalendar.io and cannot work out how to get my data to display at all

e.g

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({       
            url: '../../data/calendar.asp',
});
});
```

and the asp page displays data presented in the following way

> {
>   "events":
>   [
>   {"title":"Test Title","start":"2016-04-28T16:30:00Z","end":"2016-04-28T17:30:00Z"},
>   {"title":"Another Test Title,"start":"2016-05-05T16:30:00Z","end":"2016-05-05T17:30:00Z"},
>   {"title":"Final Test Title","start":"2016-05-05T17:30:00Z","end":"2016-05-05T17:30:00Z"}
>   ]
>   }

Any suggestions would be really appreciated

Comment: Your json looks invalid. You can check it here: http://jsonlint.com/ . Please [edit] your post and add the asp code too.

Comment: Apologies, copy and paste issue, the JSON is valid                                                {
 "events": [{
  "title": "Test Title",
  "start": "2016-04-28T16:30:00Z",
  "end": "2016-04-28T17:30:00Z"
 }, {
  "title": "Another Test Title",
  "start": "2016-05-05T16:30:00Z",
  "end": "2016-05-05T17:30:00Z"
 }, {
  "title": "Final Test Title",
  "start": "2016-05-05T17:30:00Z",
  "end": "2016-05-05T17:30:00Z"
 }]
}

Comment: As my external file prefixes with {"events":[   ]} could this be causing the issue? if so, does anyone know how I can load the data into fullcalendar.js without changing the asp page output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) to get the json from the asp page and then use the *events* element from it:

```
$(function(){
$.getJSON( "../../data/calendar.asp", function( data ) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     events: data.events
    }); 
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks you SearchAndResQ, this is very much appreciated